# Trouble Translating a WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, themes, translation

I've created an Arabic website and I am using the zippy theme from [MageeWP](http://www.mageewp.com/zippy/) the things is that I am trying to translate some strings in the theme, but I don't seem to get it working well.

In the theme functions file, there is a specification for the folder location for .PO and .MO files

I created a file **ar.mo** and put it there, but it still not working, can anybody guide to a clue?

---

- I checked in **wp_config.php** and indeed the WPLAND is set to **ar**
- I also used the [CodeStyling](http://www.code-styling.de/english/development/wordpress-plugin-codestyling-localization-en) plugin to make the translation, and it didn't work, although the plugin does not problem a .po or .mo files for ONLY `ar`.

---

#### Additionally

the source code of the zippy theme is here: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/zippy/1.0.9/

Comment: Please, show the theme code for localization.

Comment: @brasofilo thanks, for the comment, I'm not sure what do you mean, but here is a link for the complete source code of the zippy theme: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/zippy/1.0.9/

Comment: or maybe you meant the code in here: http://themes.svn.wordpress.org/zippy/1.0.9/functions.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the theme is doing it wrong (simplified code):

```
define( 'ZIPPY_THEME_BASE_URL', get_template_directory_uri() ); 
$lang = ZIPPY_THEME_BASE_URL. '/lang';
load_theme_textdomain( 'zippy', $lang );
```

It's passing an URL and [it should be a path](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain), change the `load_theme_textdomain` line to:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'zippy', get_template_directory() . '/lang');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try, should I reactivate the test for it to work?

Answer (score 1):

I had a look at the Zippy theme. There are a template called `en_US.po` inside the `lang` folder. I had a look at that as well.

If you don't have [poedit](http://www.poedit.net/) installed, download poedit now and install it on your computer. Now, make a copy of `en_US.po` and rename it `ar.po`. Open `ar.po` with poedit. Now you can do all your translations in this template. When you're done, just click save in poedit. Poedit will automatically create a `ar.mo` template when your `ar.po` is saved.

Note, this is just a quick way of doing it, as there are already a language file available that isn't yet translated.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your replay, I've done the exact same thing you described with poedit, but it didn't work, I've even deactivated and reactivated the them, but yet any changes to be seen